# How to add empty lines between lines in text.txt document?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

The purpose of the code is to add an empty line between lines in text.txt document and write some words in those empty lines.
I tried looping through every line but the file should be in read  mode only;

```
iushnaufihsnuesa
fsuhadnfuisgadnfuigasdf
asfhasndfusaugdf
suhdfnciusgenfuigsaueifcas
```

This is a sample of text.txt document
how can i implement this on this txt?

```
f = open("text.txt", 'w+')
for x in f:
f.write("\n Words between spacing")

f.close()
```

First i tried directly to just make a new line between each line and add couple of stuuf

I also thought of first making empty lines between each line and then add some words in the empty spaces but I didn't figure this out

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: i didn't have a proper working code for it in python

Comment: Maybe the best part is no part... why do you need the extra line in the first place?

Comment: I need an empty line between each line to add more words and stuff

Comment: basically just adding information between each line of the txt

Comment: So, how many lines would you expect to find in your file and how would you expect to generate the information you want to add?

Comment: about 200 lines in a txt file 
the information added between each line is the same 
like i want to add the word Deposit between each line foundin the txt file

Comment: If there are words in the in-between lines, they aren't empty lines.

Comment: In general, the safe/easy appraoch is just to read the whole file into memory, then modify write to a newly named file doing the modifications you want, then `mv` the new file to the old file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, for files in the region of 200 lines long you can store the whole file as a list of strings and add lines when re-writing the file:

```py
with open("text.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = [line for line in f]

with open("text.txt", 'w') as f:
    for line in data:
        f.write(line)
        f.write("Words between spacing\n")
```

Comment: If something goes wrong and your program dies before the writes are complete, you've lost the original contents of `text.txt`. Better to write a temporary file, then replace the original *atomically* when done.

Comment: i've done a temporary file which is better

Comment: As an aside, `data = [line for line in f]` should just be `data = list(f)`, whenver you see `[x for x in whatever]` you just want `list(whatever)`, since your list comprehension isn't doing any mapping/filtering, it's just creating a list from the iterable, and the idiomatic way to do that is to use `list`

Answer (score 1):

You can divide this operation in three steps.
In the first one, you read all the lines from the file into a `list[str]` using `f.readlines()`:

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as f: # using "read" mode
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Second is to join these lines inside the list using the `"".join(...)` function.

```
lines = "My line between the lines\n".join(lines)
```

On third step, write it down to the file:

```
with open("text.txt", "w") as f: # using "write" mode
    f.write(lines)
```

Also, you can use `f.read()` in conjunction with `text.replace("\n", ...)`:

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    full_text = f.read()

full_text = full_text.replace("\n", "\nMy desirable text between the lines\n")

with open("text.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(full_text)
```

Initial text:

```
iushnaufihsnuesa
fsuhadnfuisgadnfuigasdf
asfhasndfusaugdf
suhdfnciusgenfuigsaueifcas
```

Final text:

```
iushnaufihsnuesa
My desirable text between the lines
fsuhadnfuisgadnfuigasdf
My desirable text between the lines
asfhasndfusaugdf
My desirable text between the lines
suhdfnciusgenfuigsaueifcas
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the solution above, you will end having an aditional "added" line at the end of the text. If that is not your needs, you can test the if the ```index == len(data)``` using ```enumerate()``` to not add more text. Also you can replace ```data = [line for line in f]``` with ```data = f.readlines()```